# How is the 'checkmark' radio button displayed in Apple Notes

Tags: ios, swift

I am wondering how the 'checkmark' icon is displayed in a `UITextView` in Apple Notes. Is it a custom `view`? I'm guessing it's not an image attachment since on click it changes and it's not saveable. What do you think? How is this achieved? **Example:** [image]

Comment: In the macOS app it's an image, so most likely it's an image in iOS, too.

Comment: @vadian Okay, thanks. So do you think they have just used a NSTextAttachment and disabled saving it as an image?

Comment: I think the view is a table view or collection view

Comment: Like an embedded tableView inside the UITextView?

Comment: No a table view instead of a text view in "list mode".

Comment: I guess too Its a `tableView` with custom cells